# Why can't I destroy() / clear() a routing Manager?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm working with multiple instances of the advanced routing manager of the nokia HERE API to make multiple requests to calculate isolines at the same time. Since the amount of requests I want to make varies, I want to destroy the unused Managers. But it seems like the distroy() nor the clear() function have any effect on the Managers they are called on.

I tried to call `routingManager.destroy()` at the end of my routing callback but when I look at the routingManager in the chrome console it still shows me the routingManager:

```
g {yo: "bVQHRXUn6uNHP3B24bdt", calculateRouteResponse: Array[0], getRouteResponse: Object, qa: false, Ck: Object…}
```

Also calling `routingManager.clear()` has no effect. When I type ?`routingManager.calculateIsolineResponse` in the console I get:

```
Object {metaInfo: Object, center: Object, isolines: Array[1]}
```

Is this supposed to happen? Or is it even necessary to clean up the Managers?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clean up the Managers, you can reuse the same manager later in your session.